# Why does ffmpeg say "cannot find preset"?

Tags: ffmpeg, libx265, preset

When trying to transcode an input to x265 ffmpeg tells me "preset veryslow not found":

```
ffmpeg -i <in_file> -vf scale=xxx:yyy -c:v hevc -preset veryslow <out_file>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg needs to be compiled with both the corresponding development versions of the required libraries and the corresponding encoders/decoders enabled when invoking configure at the beginning of the build process.

In case of the Debian, this would include libx265-dev and the configure option `--enable-libx265` for the corresponding x265 / HEVC preset to be included in the corresponding binary.